# Run URL Autolaunched Flow as Default WF User

Tags: workflow, visual

I have an autolaunched visual workflow that is executed by the user clicking a URL that points to that flow. The flow updates a single field on a custom object, but I don't want to give edit rights to that object. Is there a way to run this type of flow under a specified user other than the running user (specifically admin)? ...like we do with standard workflows and the default workflow user?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a checkbox "launch flow"

Use process builder to launch the flow when checkbox is checked.

This is now an auto launched flow, which will run in system mode.

It was hard to find this clearly stated re process builder, but its clear on the flow trigger pilot docs and I got confirmation on this from the PM when these launched.

See flow trigger docs at https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_vpm_guide.meta/salesforce_vpm_guide/workflow_flow_action_considerations.htm

> Flows that are launched from workflow rules are run in system context, which means that user permissions, field-level security, and sharing rules aren’t taken into account during flow execution

Just to be clear, setting your flow property to auto launched is not enough.  It must be launched via process builder / flow trigger to run in system mode (i assume launching from apex also could run in system mode but haven't tried to do so)

Comment: Thanks for the help @gorav, but I don't think I can make this work without still giving edit rights to the user. Since the user will have to update the record in some way (checkbox as suggested) in order to execute the process.

Comment: @adam sure you can! The button that launches the flow can simply write the record id to a custom object. Then you use an auto launched flow from the custom object to do your dirty work. The user just needs create on the custom object.  Many variations on this, such as a publisher action, or an inline visualforce section on the record detail page, but should be very feasible.

Comment: Good idea @gorav. Not a fan of creating an object just for this, but maybe I can make it flexible enough for future use with other scenarios such as this. A kind of "WorkFlowTrigger" object... Thanks again for the help!

Comment: I think an object is best, but had the thought yesterday that if you really don't want one you could even trigger the flow by logging an activity to the record and firing the flow from an activity.